# In general, what ways are there to show if 2 groups are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I take it that if the number of elements of a given order n is not the same between 2 groups, then they are definitely not isomorphic. So for example if I need to show that $C_{25}$ is not isomorphic to $C_5$ x $C_5$, I need to find some $n \le 25$ for which the number of elements of order n is not the same between the 2 groups. Right?

But if I have 2 groups with the exact same number of elements of every possible order n, it's still not sufficient to establish they really are isomorphic, right? Because I need to show the mapping between them is bijective(?) So if I want to show 2 groups are isomorphic I would need to explicitly find a bijective mapping for each element that preserves the multiplication rules??

Comment: You're correct.  Clearly the number of elements of each order can be calculated in polynomial time in the size of the group, and so the comparison between two groups by this criteria can be carried out in polynomial time, too.  But GROUP-ISOMORPHISM is not known to have a polynomial-time solution; see, e.g., this column: https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/an-annoying-open-problem/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much it.  It's easy to show that two groups are *not* isomorphic by showing that something invariant under isomorphism is different in the two groups.  Like the number of elements, or the number of elements of a specific order, or the number of subgroups of a certain order, etc.

But in general, the only (sure-fire) way to show two groups *are* isomorphic is to exhibit an isomorphism between them.